# CSS class inheritance

Tags: css, inheritance

Can I create "class inheritance" in CSS? Something like:

```
.squareButton {width:20px; height:20px; margin:1px solid;}
.squareRedButton {.squareButton; background:red;}
```

Comment: Did you try SASS or LESS? http://sassmeister.com/gist/1489363b4cf4a6ccf478

Comment: @MrsEd I'm sure. It is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, just apply the desired CSS to both the class you need :

```
.squareButton, .squareRedButton {
    width : 20px; 
    height : 20px; 
    margin : 1px solid;
}

.squareRedButton { 
    background : red;
}
```

**Note**

You can pass through HTML to use several classes to perform an inheritance like following :

**CSS**

```
.squareButton {
    width : 20px; 
    height : 20px; 
    margin : 1px solid;
}

.squareRedButton {
    background:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="squareButton squareRedButton">MyButton</button>
```

Comment: or give your DOM element two classes (`<div class="squareButton red">`)

Comment: I would rather use your solution @Thilo because it better illustrate this concept of inheritance, so my answer was the CSS way.

Comment: The third way would be to use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS to augment the squareRedButton class with everything you want to inherit.

Comment: But this gets rather complicated if I have a larger tree of inheritance, with larger depth... need to repeat many classes many times...

Comment: Since CSS is not a programming language, it doesn't have this notion of pure inheritance of objects. Only cascading styling system through the first solution I gave you. But if this three of style is getting harder, follow @Thilo answer, using preprocessing CSS like SASS or LESS to be closer to a real programmed system with high level of style complexity.

Answer (score 0):

```
.squareButton{
    width : 20px; 
    height : 20px; 
    margin : 1px solid;
}

.bg-red { 
    background : red;
}


<div class="squareButton bg-red">
```

This is the short code way of doing.